# How to Iterate the options of the mat-select tag?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, ngfor

I'm trying to iterate two arrays, one to create the necessary select-fields and the other to populate the option shown in each select-field.

```html
 <div *ngFor="let subject of subjects" class="input-field col s6"> //iterating through all the subjects
   <mat-form-field>
      <mat-label>{{subject}}</mat-label> /*creating select-field for each subject*/
         <mat-select [(value)]="selectedStaff">
             <mat-option *ngFor="let faculty of facultyNames" [value]="faculty" > /*iterating facultyNames to populate options*/
                 {{faculty}} /*populating options*/
             </mat-option>
         </mat-select>
     </mat-form-field>
  </div>
```

The select-fields and options are generated as expected but when I select a option in a select-field, all the values of the other select-fields are also changed to the same option. I'm not able to individually select the option for each select-field.

I've just started learning angular and I can't find another way to implement this.
Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank You[image: All the fields are generated][image: options are shown as expected][image: all the select-fields are changed]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have the same value fou all of yours selects.

Change this.

```
<div *ngFor="let subject of subjects" class="input-field col s6">
```

for

```
<div *ngFor="let subject of subjects; let i = index" class="input-field col s6">
```

And

```
 <mat-select [(value)]="selectedStaff">
```

For

```
 <mat-select [(value)]="selectedStaff[i]">
```

and in your ts the attr `selectedStaff` need be an array whith one value for each item of `subjects` or try initializing with a empty array.

Comment: Thank you @ManuelPanizzo! Works perfectly!! I'm new to angular and I'm learning it, do you recommend any website which is user friendly and has the syntax and usages of the most commonly used ng-directives?

Comment: in youtube have a lot of free courses. but if u can pay 10 - 11 bucks in udemy.com have a lot of great angular courses! i learned there.

Comment: Thanks! I'll look into it.